# Can we get member list from a created google group using AdminSDK without super user's right

Tags: google-app-engine

As mentioned in the title, Is there anybody know how to get member list belong to a created google group using AdminSDK without super user's right. I tried on GAE but always received the following error :

「Not Authorized to access this resource/api」

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need superuser rights, thats just one way.
If the user is owner/manager of the group, she can see membership.
Also might work if you make group membership visible to all but i haven't tried it.

Comment: Without super user right it seem to be impossible. I tried to set up to delegate the right from super user to common user but failed :( Please help.

Comment: You don't really need to delegate the user, if you have a domain wide delegation active you can impersonate the owner of the group

Comment: OR you can also add A gcp service account as admin of the specific group